# Who discovered the asymptotic formula for the number of partitions of n into distinct parts?

Tags: nt.number-theory, partitions, ho.history-overview

Who was the first to develop the asymptotic formulae for the distinct parts version of $p(n)?$

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000009 cites Ayoub.  In Ayoub's book the asymptotics are relegated to an exercise (#30 on p. 196, uncredited.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Dickson, History of the Theory of Numbers, Volume 2, page 162, "G. H. Hardy and S.Ramanujan proved that the logarithm of the number $p(n)$ of partitions of $n$ is asymptotic to $\pi\sqrt{2n/3}$, and the logarithm of the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct positive integers is asymptotic to $\pi\sqrt{n/3}$." The reference is given as Proc London Math Soc 16 (1917) 131.

Answer (score 6):

Look, by Euler's theorem the number of partitions $p_{dist}(n)=p_{odd}(n)$.  Since the number of parts of a random *odd partition* (i.e. into odd part sizes) is about $O(\sqrt{n}\log n)$, removing 1 from each part gives an *even partition* of roughly the same size.  This gives
$$p_{odd}(n) \approx p_{even}(n) = p(n/2),
$$
when defined appropriately.  This shows that you really don't need a separate new asymptotic formula for $p_{dist}(n)$ if rough approximation is ok.  While informal, this argument can be made completely formal, and has been done a few times, I think.

UPDATE: I came across [Hua Luogeng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hua_Luogeng)'s paper "[On the number of partitions of a number into unequal parts](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/1989985)" (1942), which gives an analogue of Rademacher's formula for $p(n)$.

Comment: This wasn't the question being asked.  I wanted to know who was the first to develop the formula.  